# Getting Error When installing Kivy Modules

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pycharm, kivy

So to be honest I started to learn to code like two weeks ago. If anyone could help me with this problem that would be great!

so Basically when I try to install kivy-deps.angle, kivy-deps.glew, or kivy-deps.gstreamer I get a message like the one below.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle-dev==0.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle-dev==0.2.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I35e.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAYI4.png)

I Tried everything I could think of and of course the proposed solutions are a joke i get the same Error in the terminal, I have the latest version of pip

```
$ pip --version
```

pip 20.1.1 from /Users/colemanschnaak/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Since Im using a mac I already have python 2.7 pre installed I tried switching the python3 to the default.(which wasted my time)

I saw online that some people just have to type

```
$ python3 -m pip install [kivy module name]
```

but that still didnt work.

since i just started getting in to coding thats all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The current version kivy-deps.angle-dev 0.2.0 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.angle-dev/0.2.0/#files) for Python 3.6-3.8 for w32 and w64 only. No other wheels and no source code at PyPI.

If you need kivy-deps.angle-dev for a different Python or a different OS you have to compile from sources. If there is something to compile — I downloaded a wheel and didn't find any code inside it.